# Issue with Scroll/Swipe in UiAutomator

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

My test app is in the second page of display and when use `appViews.getChildByText(new UiSelector().className(android.widget.TextView.class.getName()),"<appName>",true)` it is not finding the app. (My code works fine if the app is in the first page itself)

**Below mentioned my code:**

```
public void testFindAndRunND() throws UiObjectNotFoundException {
        getUiDevice().pressHome();
        UiObject allAppsButton = new UiObject(new UiSelector().description("Apps"));
        UiObject appsTab = new UiObject(new UiSelector().text("Apps"));

        appsTab.click(); 
        UiScrollable appViews =new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().className("android.view.View")
                .scrollable(true));

        //appViews.setAsHorizontalList();
        try{

        UiObject navigationDrawerApp = appViews.getChildByText(new UiSelector().className(android.widget.TextView.class.getName()), "QA FCU", true);
        navigationDrawerApp.clickAndWaitForNewWindow(3000);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            appViews.swipeRight(1);
            System.out.println("Not Exists^&********");
        }

        UiObject navigationDrawerValidation = new UiObject(new UiSelector().packageName("com.ifs.mobilebanking.fiid9901"));

        System.out.println("Verify the App is launched!!!!!!!");
        assertTrue("Unable to find the Application", navigationDrawerValidation.exists());
    }
```

**Log is attaching below:**

```
"INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: id=UiAutomatorTestRunner
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: test=testFindAndRunND
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: class=`com.android.uiautomator.tests.demoTests`
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: current=2
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: 1
Not Exists^&********
Verify the App is launched!!!!!!!
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: numtests=3
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: stream=
Failure in testFindAndRunND:
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Unable to find the Application
    at com.android.uiautomator.tests.demoTests.testFindAndRunND(demoTests.java:105)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at com.android.uiautomator.testrunner.UiAutomatorTestRunner.start(UiAutomatorTestRunner.java:160)
    at com.android.uiautomator.testrunner.UiAutomatorTestRunner.run(UiAutomatorTestRunner.java:96)
    at com.android.commands.uiautomator.RunTestCommand.run(RunTestCommand.java:91)
    at com.android.commands.uiautomator.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:83)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:248)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: id=UiAutomatorTestRunner
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: test=testFindAndRunND
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: class=com.android.uiautomator.tests.demoTests
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: stack=junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Unable to find the Application
    at com.android.uiautomator.tests.demoTests.testFindAndRunND(demoTests.java:105)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at com.android.uiautomator.testrunner.UiAutomatorTestRunner.start(UiAutomatorTestRunner.java:160)
    at com.android.uiautomator.testrunner.UiAutomatorTestRunner.run(UiAutomatorTestRunner.java:96)
    at com.android.commands.uiautomator.RunTestCommand.run(RunTestCommand.java:91)
    at com.android.commands.uiautomator.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:83)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:248)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)"
```

So my issues are:
**1.** Not scrolling and finding the app
**2.** If I use `appViews.setAsHorizontalList();`, i get `"INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: stack=java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.android.uiautomator.core.UiScrollable.setAsHorizontalList"` Error..

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the solution, everything works, much simpler too:

```
        getUiDevice().pressHome();
    UiObject allAppsButton = new UiObject(new UiSelector().description("Apps"));
    allAppsButton.clickAndWaitForNewWindow();
    UiObject appsTab = new UiObject(new UiSelector().text("Apps"));

    appsTab.click(); 
    UiObject appViews =new UiObject(new UiSelector().resourceId("com.sec.android.app.launcher:id/apps_grid"));

    UiObject navigationDrawerApp = new UiObject (new UiSelector().text("Contacts"));
    
    while (!navigationDrawerApp.exists()){
        appViews.swipeLeft(3);
    }
   
    navigationDrawerApp.clickAndWaitForNewWindow();
```

This will search for the wanted app trough all the screens you have until it finds it. Just edit the `UiObject navigationDrawerApp = new UiObject (new UiSelector().text("Contacts"));` with your app name and run the code

Comment: Thanks Vlad.D. However I am getting a compilation error.

compile: [javac] Compiling 1 source file to /Users/bbinisha1/Desktop/AndroidPlatform/UiAutomatorTests/bin/classes [javac] /Users/bbinisha1/Desktop/AndroidPlatform/UiAutomatorTests/src/com/android/uiautomator/tests/demoTests.java:120: error: cannot find symbol [javac] UiObject appViews =new UiObject(new UiSelector().resourceId("com.sec.android.app.launcher:id/apps_grid")); [javac] ^ [javac] symbol: method resourceId(String) [javac] location: class UiSelector [javac] 1 error
But there is no error showing in the eclipse.

Comment: Trie updating the android test project to api id 7 or 10 because resourceID is used only in newer android versions. <android-sdk>/tools/android create uitest-project -n <name> -t [7 or 10] -p <path>

Answer (score 0):

I find a doc [here](http://university.utest.com/android-ui-testing-uiautomatorviewer-and-uiautomator/). but when I follows, I meet this error when compiling.

#### This post may helps one with compile errors like:

```
[javac] CalculatorTest.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
[javac] UiObject seven = new UiObject(new UiSelector().resourceId("com.android.calculator2:id/digit_7"));
[javac]                                                       ^
[javac]   symbol:   method resourceId(String)
[javac]   location: class UiSelector
[javac] CalculatorTest.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
[javac] UiObject plus = new UiObject(new UiSelector().resourceId("com.android.calculator2:id/op_add"));
[javac]                                                      ^
[javac]   symbol:   method resourceId(String)
[javac]   location: class UiSelector
[javac] CalculatorTest.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
[javac] UiObject one = new UiObject(new UiSelector().resourceId("com.android.calculator2:id/digit_6"));
[javac]                                                     ^
[javac]   symbol:   method resourceId(String)
[javac]   location: class UiSelector
[javac] CalculatorTest.java:30: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]         UiObject result = new UiObject(new UiSelector().resourceId("com.android.calculator2:id/eq"));
[javac]                                                        ^
[javac]   symbol:   method resourceId(String)
[javac]   location: class UiSelector
[javac] 4 errors
```

#### I resovled it finally by:

change the build number to 18+ in `project.properties` file.

```
# Project target.
target=android-23
```

#### Error Cause Reason:

the compiler does not use the lib which used in eclipse project, but use the lib according the target number when you use this command to generate `build.xml`:

```
android create uitest-project -n MyFirstTest -t 23 -p
```

the code above will create a `project.properties` file, which contains the target number. if the number is too low (like 5), there is no this method in the lib, then error occurs.


you can use this command to show the target id:

```
android list target
```

Hope this works!